# Codeigniter 3 - Accessing array not working as expected

Tags: php

How can I access [id]?

I have the following array (I have shortened it to just 3 entries:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [ip_address] => 124.37.249.24
 )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [ip_address] => 124.37.249.241
  )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [ip_address] => 124.37.249.241

    )
)
```

Next I am trying to build a dropdown select box and here is just a part of the code:

```
        foreach ($users_datas as $users_data) {
            $options[$users_data['id']] =  $users_data['email'];
        }
```

If I stated `$options[$users_data['id']]`, it iterates 0,1,2 and I was expecting it to come back with 3,4,5.  When I change it to `$options[$users_data['ip_address']]` I get the ip addresses as expected.  Seems to me there is some conflict or something but cannot figure it out.

How can I access `[id]`?

Comment: Are you sure the data is available as array or object? Also Please add your expected result, I think a duplicate value also can cause the issue

Comment: I have posted the array which is actually $users_datas.  Yes, as stated, I can access $users_data['ip_address'] correctly but not [id]

Comment: `$users_data['id']`  shoud get correctly if your question is correct, Can you double check again. No error found in your query

Comment: The dump of the array includes a lot of fields but I have only id, ip_address.  I can access all other fields but when it comes to ID, it just ignores my id and replies from 0 to as many fields as I have....

Comment: $options[$users_data['id']] =  $users_data['id'];  <-- If I do that, the part on the right side returns the id as expect.  Somehow $options is interfereing.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of one or your array print_r , I wounder If there is come case sensitivity or space issue on your id index

Comment: So ur $options variable is not working as you expected ?

Comment: Ah, Ajith, you are right.  What I has was correct.  I just noticed I have used $options = array() in two sections of the same page.  AHHHh.  Thank you though!

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought I found the problem as i has declared two $options on the same page but found even when renamed, same problem.

Comment: Can you print_r before and after your forech loop where you assign id to your $options variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212902/discussion-between-spreaderman-and-ajith).